# Figcaption overflowing image width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a `col-md-4` and inside i have a `figure` and a `figcaption`, on the the `hover` action should be showed the figcaption with two buttons, the effect is working, but the `figcaption` in overflowing the image width. Any suggestion?

Note that when I pass the mouse over the blank space, the effect keeps working, when it should work only if I pass de mouse over the image:

Print:[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <figure>
            <img src="img/hidrau.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <figure>
            <img src="img/Gescolar.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
            <figcaption>
            <a href="http://hidrauriomangueiras.com.br" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legenda">Visitar</button></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/hidraurio" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legenda">Github</button></a>
            </figcaption>
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
          <figure>
            <img src="img/hidrau.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
          </figure>
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
#portfolio figure{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#portfolio img{
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

#portfolio figure figcaption{
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -80px;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: white;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#portfolio figure:hover figcaption {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
#portfolio figure:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `:hover` pseudo is activated when you hover over the `figure` element, which is currently using a `block` display, meaning it is taking up 100% of its parent's width. Here's two ways of solving this one:

**display: inline-block;**

This will adjust the width to it's contents, in this case that being the `img` element.

```
#portfolio figure{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRVgbW)

*note: this will shrink the whole figure to that width, so the `figcaption` background will not span the entire width, if you need that...*

**span inside the figure**

To keep the figure at 100% width, instead of activating the effect on the `figure` element, simply wrap it's contents in another element, such as a span, and apply the hover styles to that.

HTML

```
<figure>
  <span>
    <img src="img/Gescolar.png" alt="Hidraurio Mangueiras">
    <figcaption>
      <a href="http://hidrauriomangueiras.com.br" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legenda">Visitar</button></a>
      <a href="https://github.com/tiagosilveiraa/hidraurio" target="_blank"><button class="btn-legenda">Github</button></a>
    </figcaption>
  </span>
</figure>
```

CSS

```
#portfolio figure>span:hover figcaption {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
}
#portfolio figure>span:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
}
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdXLLe)